# Comparison method violation and stackoverflow

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to display images (as image icons for `JLabel`s).
Everything works fine when I am NOT trying to display images, i.e.:

```
for (int i=0;i<value;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<value;j++)
        {
            c.gridx=i;
            c.gridy=j;
            JLabel element = new JLabel("!");
            pane.add(element,c);
        }
    }
```

However if I do this:

```
for (int i=0;i<value;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<value;j++)
        {
            c.gridx=i;
            c.gridy=j;
            JLabel element = new JLabel();
            element.setIcon(wall);
            pane.add(element,c);
        }
    }
```

It will produce a good amount of error messages.
Console output: http://pastebin.com/teuuWjRX

The code: (pastebin version w/ syntax highlighting: http://pastebin.com/2utFJ0UM)

```
package tut;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Main extends JFrame{
//private static int value;
public Main()
{
    int value=151;//151
    ImageIcon wall = new ImageIcon();
    try
    {
        BufferedImage tempImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(("/resources/images/test.png")));
        wall = new ImageIcon(tempImage.getScaledInstance(4, 4, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    }
    catch (IOException e){}
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    for (int i=0;i<value;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<value;j++)
        {
            c.gridx=i;
            c.gridy=j;
            JLabel element = new JLabel();
            element.setIcon(wall);
            pane.add(element,c);
        }
    }
    //Main Frame
    setTitle("Example1");
    setSize(value*8,value*8);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Main test1= new Main();
}
}
```

My questions are:

- Why does it raise the exception in comparison? (Everything seems to
  be fine from my point of view)
- Can stackOverFlow problem be caused because of each time object declaration? (As I don't see any other problem in the loop).

P.s.: Is getScaledInstance okay to use or there's a better method?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Overall, I did not find any real problem with the code, the only thing I can say that the problem is not with scaling. Parsing little-sized images (like 8x8 or 4x4) w/o scaling also produces an error, however everything is fine for parsing images of size 16x16 or higher or scaling to 16x16. It could be kind of a problem with placing/adding little-sized images (i.e. elements) to the layout.

Comment: GridBagLayout seems a little oversized for this task. Why not a simple GridLayout?

Comment: GridLayout produces the same.

Comment: Try doing the creation of the GUI on the EDT. In the main: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){  Main test1= new Main(); }});`

Comment: Marco, no changes, but thanks:)

Comment: As pastebin is blocked for me I can't see the error messages but the code worked fine for me. Can you check if you this.getClass().getResource() returns correct URL

Comment: file:/C:/Users/Denis/Desktop/Java%20Workspace/JavaSwingTut/bin/resources/images/test.png
Path is correct, and btw program itself executes normally, but still raises exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `wall` as an Icon. And `wall` is created in a try block where you don't even log exceptions raised.

The problem could be here : maybe you have an exception (IOException) raised at the icon creation and you can't see it.

---

you can try the JLabel constructor `public JLabel(Icon image)` instead of empty constructor

Apolo

Comment: Sounds like a comment ;)

Comment: Added output to catch block, everything is fine with image processing. (at this point at least). Btw, for small values like 21 everything also works fine. Thanks for the suggestion:)

Comment: sorry alex2410 but I don't have enougth reputation yet to comment a question... so I made it an answer =)

Comment: Denis, have you tried the constructor `public JLabel(Icon image)` ?

Comment: well... I'm stucked =)